# Clickable option with action in select

Tags: vue.js

I'm working on a Vue file and have a select

```
 <select v-if="show">
     <option v-on:click="test()" value=""> someData</option>
     <option>otherdata</option>
 </select>

[...] 
 var instance = new Vue({
        el: "#General",
        [...]
        methods:{
            test: function(){
                alert('youre goddam right');
            }
            [...]
        }
    [...]
 }
```

So What i'm trying to do is to display my datas someData and otherdata. That works great but what i want it's when the user click on firstData, the action "test" append, and an alert comes up but that doesn't work here. I tried with the `v-on:click` but nothing happend.

Thanks for the help

Comment: `That works great but when the user click on firstData, the action "test" append, and an alert comes up`... Well, yes, that's what you have written in your code (binding test to the @click event of your first option). Are you trying to do something different? And what?

Comment: Sorry, i'm changing that @Cobaltway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes so it appears that the click event is not triggered for an `<option>` element. Here is one of the many fix available: using the input event on the select instead, and filter the value.

```js
var instance = new Vue({
 el: "#General",
 methods:{
  test: function(value) {
   if (value === "choice1") {
    alert('youre goddam right');
   }
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="General">
 <select v-on:input="test($event.target.value)">
   <option value="choice1">someData</option>
   <option>otherdata</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok so i tried that. It works almost. First I didn't have to add `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.js"></script>`. Worked without it. And it works unless i add a `class="select2"`

Comment: The script tag is for demo only, obviously. You should have a proper import somewhere on your code (or use a package manager). Please be more precise for your second problem.

Comment: when i do `<select v-on:input="test($event.target.value)">`, It works great.
But it's 'ugly'. When i do `<select class="select2" v-on:input="test($event.target.value)">` it looks good but doesn't work anymore

Comment: Yes, don't forget to add the value property if you want to filter by value. Otherwise, you can also filter by innerHTML, etc.